# DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid leaking memory in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, memory-leaks, directx, sharpdx

I'm working on an app using SharpDX to render DirectX content to a DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid in Windows Phone 8.

I've found that, if the app goes out to the photo picker or suspends/resumes through Fast Application Resume, memory utilization will increase by about ~2mb and prior resources will not be reclaimed. This means a DirectX-based app using DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid will eventually run out of memory on user-initiated actions.

The leak starts once DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid.SetBackgroundContentProvider is invoked with a SurfaceBackgroundContentProvider. I'm using a DrawingSurfaceBackgroundContentProviderNativeBase implementation that has empty method bodies for all abstract members.

An isolated repro can be found [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=16e5f6030dcb8991&id=16E5F6030DCB8991!25658). Repro steps are: build and run the app, click "choose photo", hit the hardware back button, observe memory spike.

Anyone else seeing similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in SharpDX, which has been resolved in [this commit](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/commit/3ee777787d8f3b86e242e1614e0ab0529b017a71).